# Including authentication strings in a repository

Tags: git, authentication, repository

What is the best solution for storing possibly sensitive database connection strings (that would usually go in an `app.config`) in a repository? I don't feel nervous pushing them up to our current private development git repo, but if we ever publish this project open source, our database information would be available for the world to see.

Hardcoding the connection strings would be suicide, but I need to include my app.config in the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an app.config.template file and sanitize any sensitive information. Push that to your public repo instead of the app.config, along with instructions to the end user to copy it, and fill in the necessary fields to create their own app.config.

Comment: You could also do a pre-build script to do this, I think.

Comment: As part of a 'make config' operation, certainly. Thats an even better idea @ChristianStewart